# Install RIM Tablet apps programmatically

Tags: blackberry-playbook

As everyone know, Blackberry smartphones can **install apps programmatically**. So, how to do it on a playbook? I've searched around the internet, but nothing found :(

Thanks in advance for any response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean having one app programmatically install another app, this is not currently possible.  Apps are "sandboxed" -- tightly restricted in what they can do -- and there is no API allowing this.  It's quite possible RIM will never expose this capability to us, even when the native SDK is released.

If you mean programmatically installing from outside the PlayBook, this can be done.  Search for "side-loading" and you'll find at least one AIR-based tool which someone built by reverse engineering the protocol.  This technique requires the tablet be put into development mode, and may involve other restrictions depending on what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Yep, I found my answer. By far, there is only one way to install apps inside Playbook is directly download from App World.

Side-loading is an approach to install apps outside the device (developer mode)

Anyway, thanks Peter ;)